# How to verify Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability

Tags: android, android-security

I work on an android library and recently our partners complained about Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability. So, we made a fix according to https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9294009. Is there a way to verify this? We want to verify this is fixed before releasing a new version.